# Cygwin malloc overrides another memory in heap

Tags: c, cygwin, malloc

I have a strange error when try to malloc some memory. I've a pointer to a struct which is "malloced" and I want another struct. So I call malloc again and the pointer what malloc give back is point an empty space - so far it's ok. Then I memset the allocated area and the memset overrides another variable which is still in use. 
The first struct in the memory is in 0x1643c98 and the given pointer to the second is 0x1643bf8 but I want to malloc 200 byte. The code:

```
data_t *data = get_head_data(); 
int length = data->head.length;
data_t *new_data = malloc(length); 
memset(new_data, 0x00, length); // this line override the perivously malloced data 
//some other operation
```

I use window xp (32 bit) and cygwin, with gcc 3.4.4. processor is intel core 2 duo.
Any idea whats wrong or what should be the problem? 
Thanks in advance.

EDIT: Sorry I was a totally wrong track. There is a buggy function which is call free unexpected. When I call malloc later the the previous address is in the memory and I think it's a valid, but it was free()-ed.
Thanks all the advice!

Comment: Please edit your code or post more of it: we don't know what `result` is in that memset call.

Comment: Are the result argument in memset and the new_data pointer supposed to be the same pointer?

Comment: `memset(new_data, 0x00, length);` cannot overwrite anything outside the memory block allocated for `new_data`. You're probably writing outside the margin of the other array. But I'd need to see more code to be sure...

Comment: This still isn't your exact code; you have an extraneous `data_t` on the end of the `int length` line. Please create a minimal test case that reproduces your issue and post it EXACTLY in its entirety so that we can see what you are actually doing.

Comment: What is the relationship between `length` (`data->head.length`) and `sizeof (data_t)`?

Comment: Ok I try to create test case and post it the result.

Comment: Hmm... I made test cases and I can't reproduce the error in test cases. I also made different exe files and there is one that works and other two not. It's weird...

Answer (score 1):

If you need to set the newly allocated memory to 0 - use `calloc`. You're probably confusing pointers, sizes, and variables - check your code again.

Answer (score 1):

`data_t *new_data = malloc(length);`

Unless `sizeof(data_t)` is 1, that line is likely to be an error.  You are allocating `length` bytes.  If you want an array of `length` `data_t`'s, then you need to allocate `sizeof(data_t)*length` bytes.

A better solution would be to use `calloc`, as @littleadv suggests.  That function takes separate arguments for number_of_items, and sizeof_item, so it's harder to get wrong.